# Adding car to my SENTRI account

Tags: sentri

I’m adding my car to my SENTRI account. What does U.S. government issued license plate mean? Should I put yes or no?
Thank you !

Answer (score 9):

This is asking whether the vehicle is an official US Federal Government vehicle, with government plates.

Right below that question on the Trusted Traveler portal it has the following explanation:

> [image: U.S. government issued license plates are those that are issued by any US Federal Government agency, e.g. Department of State, Department of Homeland Security, U.S. Postal Service, etc. and does not include license plates issued by individual states.]

If your vehicle is a private vehicle then select "No"